# angular custom directive required validation is not updated

Tags: validation, angularjs, directive, required

i created my own directive, replacing an input field with a custom made input field. However, the validation of the required field never seems to update and instead is always false.

Other directives inside my directive like ng-class do work.

I have created a plunker here to show this problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NuZNAJceL0MVX8i6RK9n?p=preview

Can anybody help me out how to make sure that the required validation is properly updated?

Comment: seems a lot more compicated than it needs to be. You are running into isolated scope issues creating a scope within directive. What is overall objective of the directive?

Comment: I quickly scanned the source code and it looks to me that you want the input type=number to be displayed as a simple type=text. Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/fWtltPMqTT0EE47KUxei?p=preview

Comment: I am still learning the way of correctly writing directives. What i want is to have a directive that replaces an <input> element with my own <input> element with different behaviour. For example, when the type=number is given, i want to actually write out my own input with type=text and put my custom validation in the directive (based on regex). I managed to get that to work. What I want now is that have standard angular directives to work with it, like ng-required. However, i am running into problems there

Comment: critical part to understand is if you don't declare isolated scope in the directive,  the scope will be that of the parent.... or form in your case and `ng-required` will work fine. Can access attributes in link or compile callbacks without needing to create isolated scope in many situations like simple dom manipulation